# How to scale 386*389 png image to 20*20 in pixels

Tags: unity-game-engine, png, chess, image-size

I am creating a chess game in unity and need my pieces to be 20*20.

I currently have a chess king (png file) that is 386 by 389 pixels and when I try to resize it it gets all blurry.

I have tried using Gimp scale image and IrfanView to no avail.

Can anyone help?

This is the image in case that's helpful.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkUp9.png

Edit: I made the board bigger and my pieces bigger so I could avoid "pixel space"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not saying it's impossible to algorithmically scale to that size without blurriness, but I've never seen a scaling algorithm that would do a good job. At 20x20 pixels, you are in the "pixel art" realm, where you'd need to manually set pixels to get good results.

The reason I doubt a scaling algorithm will do well with this task, is that it requires judgment on what details are important to express. E.g. The tines on a queen's crown are meaningful as iconography, because humans have seen enough crowns to know that pointy bits on the top are what make its "crownliness".

I would put on the "pixel artist" hat or hire one. Use the scaled down image as a guide. Create an extra layer on top of it. Fill in your black pixels first, and then in a second pass, add grey or mid-opacity pixels to the jagged edges to smooth. You've only got a dozen pieces to do. ;)

Comment: Ok thank you :)
I have one question, I would prefer to not use pixel art is there anything I can do? Maybe with the unity engine specifically?.

Comment: I think it's valuable to narrow the problem to the image itself. Because any technique or trick you might be able to do within Unity will also be possible with image manipulation in a paint program. So for example, you could run a post-processing filter or shader in Unity to increase contrast. But you could perform the same operation of increasing contrast inside of a paint program, and that is a simpler and more direct solution that won't require CPU/GPU at runtime.